# Calling rename() without overwriting unexpected data and without overwriting with unexpected data

Tags: c, linux, posix, rename

Say you have a file named `foo` that contains some definite sequence of bytes `X`, and you want to atomically replace it with a file named `bar` that contains a byte sequence `Y`. This is typically done with the `rename()` system call---in this case, by invoking `rename("bar", "foo")`. However, you want the two following constraints to be observed:

1. The replacement should only be performed if the file named `bar` does contain the data `Y`, otherwise it should fail.
2. The replacement should only be performed if the file named `foo` does contain the data `X` otherwise it should fail.

How to do that correctly?

To prevent `foo` and `bar` from being edited before we call `rename()`, we can lock them with `fnctl` or equivalent. But locks only help to prevent modifications of the file data, they have no effect on directory entries, so that, by the time `rename()` does its magic, the data `foo` or `bar` refer to might not be the same.

Two examples of data loss scenarios, for the two constraints described above:

1. - We've locked the file named `bar` and made sure that it contains the data `Y`
   - Before we've time to replace `foo` with `bar`, some program replaces `bar` with a file previously named `qux` that holds the data `Z`.
   - We replace `foo` with `bar`.
   - Now the file `foo`, which we expected to contain the data of `bar`, contains instead the data of `qux`. Both the data of `foo` and `bar` is lost.
2. - We've locked the file named `foo` and made sure that it contains the data `X`.
   - Before we've time to replace `foo` with `bar`, some program replaces `foo` with a file previously named `qux` that holds the data `Z`.
   - We replace `foo` with `bar`.
   - Now the file `foo` does contain the data of `bar`, but the data of the file `qux` has been lost in the process.

Comment: Why do you care that `foo` will be edited if you replace it anyway?

Comment: @EugeneSh. It's for a deduplication tool. I want to replace `foo` with a link to another file that holds the same data as `foo`, without losing data in the process.

Comment: This is possible on most CoW filesystems like Btrfs, which has an ioctl to verify and dedup specific ranges in the kernel.

Comment: This doesn't really make any sense.  Files don't have names.  There are names in directories that refer to files, and I suppose that's what you mean, but....if you have an open file handle on the file that you accessed through the link "bar", and it contains the data you want, and some other process changes "bar" so that it references another file, your process still has the original file and the data is still there.  Even if it doesn't have any links left in the file system, you can still modify the data and create a link named "foo".

Comment: @WilliamPursell You can certainly modify the data of a file that has been unlinked, or even copy its data to a new file, but you can't rename, link to it or link from it, and so on, since, for these functions to work, the file's directory entry must be reachable, which it isn't at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment:

> It's for a deduplication tool. I want to replace foo with a link to another file that holds the same data as foo, without losing data in the process

I think you have an XY problem. You cannot make the `rename` operation atomic with respect to contents of the files. But your goal is just to avoid data loss if a file changes unexpectedly during the deduplication process. That's amenable to other approaches, like keeping a hardlink to the old file and restoring it (either to the original name, or to a special recovery area) *after* performing the rename and then comparing to detect that it's changed.

However there are a lot of fundamental issues that still make this problematic, starting with at least:

- A process may have an open handle for write on the old file, without having modified it yet, and may modify and close it after you deduplicate it. In that case the close operation will orphan it and the data will be lost.
- Any process intending to modify one of the files being deduplicated will modify all duplicates at the same time once they're hard-linked, probably contrary to your expectation.

If your goal is deduplicating to save space, but keeping semantics to allow modification, you really need a filesystem that deduplicates fs blocks with copy-on-write semantics, not hard links. On the other hand, if you want hard links, you should treat the whole tree being deduplicated as essentially read-only during **and after** the deduplication operation.

Comment: After a quick check, it seems indeed to better to rely on a filesystem feature. Still, it's  somewhat regrettable that POSIX doesn't allow more control on directory entries. Looking at the Linux kernel, the `rename()` function in the fs layer takes directory entries and inode as arguments.